# Unable to execute a journey builder journey - Contact Builder/Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I've been going round and round trying to fix/resolve this issue.

1. New DE has been created and linked to primary key in DE
2. Primary key in DE is 'SubscriberKey'
3. DE has been set as Root

The issue I seem to be having is I'm unable to add the email address in Channel Address Order.

When i setup the entry with the DE and test this is the error i get:

> Event.EmailAudience-6ce800cc-9b18-18f4-aee2-0b16aa7a8e8a.EmailAddress >cannot be used in the Interaction Defaults email list. Event key does not >correspond to the interactions entry event key

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "New DE has been created and linked to primary key in DE"? Are you referring to creating a new Population in Contact Builder and binding the SubscriberKey to the Contact Key in the Contact Record?

Comment: Hi Elliot, I really should have proof read that. I meant to say New attribute group has been created, and Sub Key in my DE linked through 1 to 1 relationship to the contact key.

Comment: OK, do you have either a root relationship (if you created the Attribute Set in previous versions of Contact Builder) or a Population configured?

Comment: I've got populations configured. What should the data structure look like with populations?

Comment: The error you report is quite unusual. If you have a few mins, I'd be happy to assist over a webinar as it's going to be hard to debug through more comments. [Connect with me](https://www.linkedin.com/in/eliot) and I'll set up a brief webinar. I will then post the solution as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I setup a webinar with @Keef to review the issue that he was experiencing. I was able to assist him in resolving this issue and his journey is now functioning correctly.

For the benefit of others, here's what to try if you experience the error message when publishing an Interaction:

> Event.xxxxxx.xxxxxx cannot be used in the Interaction Defaults email list. Event key does not correspond to the interactions entry event key.

In @Keef's case there were a couple of root causes:

### Population Configuration

The Event Source Data Extension had been added to an Attribute Group and there was no Population created. We deleted the Event Source DE from the Attribute Group (it doesn't need to be there) and we created a Population (formerly known as a 'root relationship' in earlier versions), linking a Data Extension containing all Contacts to the Contact Key of the Contact Record.

### Channel Address Order

Ensure that one of the following has been configured:

1. The Email Address from your Event Source Data Extension is added as a Channel Address Order in Contact Builder (from the Contacts Configuration page) or,
2. In the Settings page for the Journey, select `EMAIL ADDRESS FIELDS FROM ENTRY SOURCE` as the Primary Email address.

Comment: This helped me - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had this error when I created a new version of a journey interaction with a different Entry. My solution to the error was:

On the `Settings` page for the Journey, I selected `Use email attribute from Contacts` as the Default Email address.

Answer (score 0):

FYI for others out there: I got this error when trying to activate a journey I started working on a while ago.

This journey is based on a Data Extension entry event with an associated Automation that adds records to it.

Turn out the reason for the error was that the Data Extension was moved to another folder during the time that passed since the creation of the journey.

Solution was to delete the entry event, save the journey and to configure the entry event again.

NB: the browser console showed the failing validation and the "Use email attribute from Entry Source" option kept resetting itself after each validation.