# Testing or Activating Journey results in triggered send error

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, journeybuilder

I am testing a few journeys I created, which should fire when a new contact is detected in a Data Extension. Configuration seems fine, the only filter I set is Email=notnull for testing purposes.

But when Testing or trying to activate the journey the following messages comes up in red:
[image]

I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong, as I have tested the exact same method on another instance and the journey fired, and email was send just fine.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You usually get this message if there is an error in the AMPscript code of the email selected in the email activity. Try if an email without AMPscript works.

If it does, validate the email you wanted to use in the journey in email studio/content builder. Do so using the arrow-icon and "Validate". ([Marketing Cloud Documentation: Validate an email](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/validate/validate_an_email/))

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot [Markus Slabina](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/36218/markus-slabina)! Your answer pointed me in the right direction and made me analyze what I had done.

Here's how I solved this:

- I changed the email I was using to a blank one with no AMPscript in it, but that did not solve my problem. I was still getting the error message.

I then remembered that Content Builder Approvals are in place, so I sent the test email to Approvals, approved it, re-built the Journey, clicked Test and it partially worked.

I was now getting the error

> Event key does not correspond to the interactions entry event key

Which I was able to solve thanks to [Eliot Harper](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/5449/eliot-harper)'s response to this question:

[Unable to execute a journey builder journey - Contact Builder/Journey Builder](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/141006/unable-to-execute-a-journey-builder-journey-contact-builder-journey-builder)

1. Remember to check if Approvals for Content Builder are in place and
   first approve an email before including it in a Journey
2. Make sure that In the Settings page for the Journey, select `EMAIL
   ADDRESS FIELDS FROM ENTRY SOURCE` as the Primary Email address.

If that does not work then:

- Ensure there is a Population created in Contact Builder that links
  the Data Extension's Primary key (in my case Email) to Contact Key.